# wordpress contact form 7 date field not showing correctly

Tags: wordpress, date, cross-browser

I have a standard contact 7 form in which I need to include datepicker for arrival and departure dates. I installed datepicker for CF7 plugin, but since it is not tested with the latest version of wordpress, I can't seem to get it to work. It shows two input boxes instead of datepicker for my arrival and departure dates. So, I put date field instead and it works fine. Only in chrome, though. It doesn't show properly in firefox. Someone suggested on the web to put  `add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );` in `functions.php`, but eventhough I put it there nothing helps.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing javascript based datepicker was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this i think this will suit you https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, this plugin isnt compatible with the latest version of WP, I tried using it, as I said in my original question.